# Версия Laravel в проекте

Tags: laravel, composer

знатоки! Прошу не кидать тряпками, а объяснить.
Пытаюсь выяснить версию Laravel проекте. Файл *composer.json* говорит **laravel/framework": "5.3.***, а `php artisan --version` выдаёт "*Laravel Framework 6.18.13*".
Соответственно возник вопрос, а какая версия реально на проекте? Видимо, я не совсем верно понимаю синтаксис *composer.json*, потому как считаю, что при такой записи будет установлена любая версия из *5.3* и не выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
тут есть const VERSION = 'XXXXXX';

Comment: const VERSION = '5.3.31'; Выходит, артисан выдаёт неверную информацию?